# TFS: How to Completely Ignore files by name-pattern (or glob?)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfvc

We have migrated a project from Mercurial to TFS 2013. The project uses ASP.NET Web API and TypeScript and there are many, many automatically generated files.

Under Mercurial, we used `.hgignore` to ignore many `.js` and `.js.map` and other auto-generated files. This was done using globbing and wild-cards in certain subdirectories.

Under TFS, we have only found how to '*exclude*' these files from a commit - we can't find a way to entirely remove them.

The problem with excluding files is twofold: firstly, the exclude-list seems to be reset under certain circumstances and, secondly, if the exclude-list is flooded with these files, it is difficult to use it for its correct purpose: partial commits.

How do you properly exclude files from version control, under TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Team Foundation Server Version Control (TFVC) has a similar mechanism. `.tfignore`, with a very silimar syntax to what you're used to. [More information can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore).

You can also enable the [Forbidden patterns check-in policy](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2012/10/15/available-check-in-policies-for-team-foundation-server-2012.aspx) to ensure that people don't explicitly add files to source control (explicit add overrides .tfignore). It ships as part of the [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f).